# Magento 2 - How to get product attribute in order API

Tags: magento2, sales-order, rest-api

I added two new product attributes to a product called

netsuite_internal_id & ava_tax_code

if I do a GET to /rest/V1/products/{sku}, I can see them in custom_attributes.attribute_code.

When a customer places and order I need those product attribute to show up in the "items" node. When doing a GET to /rest/V1/orders/{orderId}

ORDER REST API
[image]

PRODUCT REST API
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to show the attribute on order API under items:

> **etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface">
        <attribute code="custom_attribute" type="boolean"/>
</extension_attributes>
```

> **etc/di.xml**

```
 <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface">
                <plugin name="order_item_custom_attribute"
                        type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\OrderItemRepositoryPlugin" />
        </type>
```

> **Vendor\Module\Plugin\OrderItemRepositoryPlugin**

** Make sure the params of the functions (afterGet, afterGetList and getOrderItemExtensionAttributes) have the type for OrderItem, not Order

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemSearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

/**
 * Class OrderItemRepositoryPlugin
 */
class OrderItemRepositoryPlugin
{
    protected $orderItemExtensionFactory;
    protected $productFactory;

    /**
     * OrderItemRepositoryPlugin constructor
     *
     * @param OrderItemExtensionFactory $orderItemExtensionFactory
     * @param ProductFactory $productFactory
     */
    public function __construct(    
        OrderItemExtensionFactory $orderItemExtensionFactory,
        ProductFactory $productFactory)
    {
        $this->orderItemExtensionFactory = $orderItemExtensionFactory;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param OrderItemRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderItemInterface $orderItem
     *
     * @return OrderItemInterface
     */
    public function afterGet(OrderItemRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderItemInterface $orderItem)
    {
        $customAttribute = $orderItem->getData('product_attribute');
 
        $extensionAttributes = $orderItem->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();

        $extensionAttributes->setBuspack($customAttribute);
        $orderItem->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $orderItem;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param OrderItemRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderItemSearchResultInterface $searchResult
     *
     * @return OrderItemSearchResultInterface
     */
    public function afterGetList(OrderItemRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderItemSearchResultInterface $searchResult)
    {
        $orders = $searchResult->getItems();

        foreach ($orders as &$order) {
            $order = $this->getOrderItemExtensionAttributes($order);
        }

        return $searchResult;
    }

 /**
     *
     * @param OrderItemInterface $orderItem
     *
     * @return OrderItemInterface
     */
    protected function getOrderItemExtensionAttributes(OrderItemInterface $orderItem)
    {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
        $product->load($orderItem->getProductId());
        $customAttribute = $product->getCustomAttribute();

        if (isset($customAttribute)) {
            $orderItemExtension = $this->orderItemExtensionFactory->create();
            $orderItemExtension->setCustomAttribute($isBuspack);

            $orderItem->setExtensionAttributes($orderItemExtension);
        }
        
        return $orderItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I am getting ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractExtensibleModel::getCustomAttribute(),
0 passed in /app/app/code/HawkRidge/RestOrder/Plugin/OrderItemRepositoryPlugin.php on line 81 and exactly 1 expected in

Comment: $customAttribute = $product->getCustomAttribute();

Comment: because in the extension_attributes I named my attribute custom_attribute, I used $product->getCustomAttribute() function. 
Did you adjust your attribute code and the way you call it on $product?

Comment: Eyyy! it worked! Thank you so much man. Anyway I can send you a gift? message me if you have Venmo or Facebook pay!

Comment: Happy to help! good luck

Comment: I tried getting the attribute "size" as <attribute code="custom_attribute"> to <attribute code="size"> in etc/extension_attributes.xml and changing  $customAttribute = $product->getCustomAttribute(); to $customAttribute = $product->getSize(); in Vendor\Module\Plugin\OrderItemRepositoryPlugin but it is not giving that attribute value on api call /rest/V1/orders. Any other value to change?

Comment: This it will show under extension_attributes. Instead, how to add the value ander item?

Comment: I successfully get the product attribute but not saving in the database

Answer (score 0):

> **etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface">
        <attribute code="product_attribute" type="int"/>
</extension_attributes>
```

> **etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="attribute_plugin"
                type="<vendor>\<Module>\Plugin\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface"/>
    </type>
```

> **Plugin\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface**

```
namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Plugin\Sales\Api;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

class OrderRepositoryInterface
{

    protected $orderItemExtensionFactory;
    protected $productFactory;

    public function __construct(
        OrderItemExtensionFactory $orderItemExtensionFactory,
        ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderItemExtensionFactory = $orderItemExtensionFactory;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderInterface $order
     * @return OrderInterface
     */
    public function afterGet(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        OrderInterface $order
    ) {
        /** @var OrderExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes */
        $order = $this->getOrderItemExtensionAttributes($order);

        return $order;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return OrderSearchResultInterface
     */
    public function afterGetList(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        OrderSearchResultInterface $searchResult
    ) {
        $orders = $searchResult->getItems();

        foreach ($orders as &$order) {
            $order = $this->getOrderItemExtensionAttributes($order);
        }

        return $searchResult;
    }

    /**
     * items of order
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface
     */
    protected function getOrderItemExtensionAttributes(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order)
    {
        if (null !== $order->getItems()) {
            /** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface $orderItem */
            foreach ($order->getItems() as $orderItem) {

                if ($orderItem->getExtensionAttributes() && $orderItem->getExtensionAttributes()->getGiftMessage()) {
                    continue;
                }
                $product = $this->productFactory->create();
                $product->load($product->getIdBySku($orderItem->getSku()));
                $customAttr = $product->getCustomAttribute();

                /** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtension $orderItemExtension */
                $orderItemExtension = $this->orderItemExtensionFactory->create();
                $orderItemExtension->setReturnDays($customAttr);


                $orderItem->setExtensionAttributes($orderItemExtension);
            }
        }
        return $order;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it is not showing up. Does this make all of them show up?

Comment: This it will show under extension_attributes. Instead, how to add the value ander item?